# Qt: Questions about QMap thread-safety

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, thread-safety, qmap

I am using Qt5 on Windows 7.
In my current app, I have the following (simplified here):

```
QMap<int, QString> map;

int _WorkerThread_(int index)  
{  
    QString new_element = "whatever";   
    ...   
    map.insert(index, new_element);  // [Q1]  
    ...   
}   

int _MainThread_()   
{   
    int i;
    ...   
    i = some_value();
    map.remove(i); // [Q2]   
    ...    
}
```

I have 2 questions about the above code and related to `QMap` thread-safety (I didn't find much info about it in the Qt documentation):

**1)** Is `map.insert(..)` - *see code-line marked [Q1]* - safe to be used like it is above, when launching more `_WorkerThread_` threads simultaneously?

**2)** How safe/thread-safe is to remove an element from the `QMap` - *see code-line marked [Q2]* - when (somehow) it is guaranteed that the value of `i` is not among the indexes currently in use by working threads?

**[Edit]:**
So, you're saying I should use a mutex or what?

Comment: QMap is "reentrant" defined here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-reentrancy.html#reentrant .  My conclusion is NOT thread safe. ie 1) No, 2) No.

Comment: Not thread safe, insertions and removal modify the container, regardless of the specific index you are working on.

Comment: Yes, the simplest solution is to guard access to the map with a mutex.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov : And a complex one...? Even if it sounds like a joke, it isn't - I would be very interested to see the alternative(s)   :-)

Comment: There are thread safe maps, for example, ones provided by [junction](https://github.com/preshing/junction) library. Depending on the architecture of your app, it also may be possible to eliminate the global map and use other means of inter-thread communication, such as Qt signals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QMap **is not** thread-safe, **but** reentrant.

To answer to your edit, you can use Qt provided tools like classes (ex: ***QMutex***) or fundamental functions (ex: ***QCoreApplication::postEvent()***)

For more informations, see Qt explanations here : http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-reentrancy.html

Hope that help !